# Wrong answer for AND operation

Tags: c

I am trying to perform AND operation on buffer which is filled with all 1.
I am writing the below code,

```
unsigned char pTemp[1024];
 memset(pTemp,0xFF,1024);
printf("AND - %d ",((unsigned char)pTemp[0] && 0x2));
```

I am getting the answer - 1 .

Please let me know what is happening. Provide the solution.

Comment: `&&` is not a bitwise "and" operation - you want the `&` operator.

Answer (score 8):

The bitwise AND operator is `&`, not `&&`. The latter one is the logical operator used to combine boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

`&&` is logical operator, while `&` is bitwise operator, they're different.

`2 && 1` gives non-zero, and `2 & 1` gives `0`.

I believe you want `&` here.

Answer (score 0):

The & is the logic operator, and if you don't feel confortable with this kind of operation, you can define it as you remember better. Much more if you have to use it a lot. See the next example:

```
#define AND(x,y) (x) & (y)             //definition of custom operation.
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    unsigned char pTemp[1024];

    memset(pTemp,0xFF,1024);
    printf("and:%d", AND(pTemp[0], 0x2));      //AND(x,y) returns the operation

}
```

This might do the task more confortable if you have to use a lot of operations or you want to define a little bit more complex operations.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it really "confuses" the reader, but it's probably not a good idea to give a new name for such a basic operation.